# Reading includes from idl file in custom task

Tags: gradle

I want to make my gradle build inteligent when building my model.

To acquire this I was planning to read schema files, acquire what is included and then build firstly included models (if they are not present).

I'm pretty new to `Groovy` and `Gradle`, so please that into account.

What I have:

1. `build.gradle` file on root directory, including **n** subdirectories (subprojects added to `settings.gradle`). I have only one **gradle build file**, because I defined tasks like:

   ```
   subprojects {
       task init
       task includeDependencies(type: checkDependencies)
       task build
       task dist
       (...)
   }
   ```

I will return to checkDependencies shortly.

2. Schema files located externally, which I can see.
   Each of them have from 0 to 3 lines of code, that say about dependencies and looks like that:

   ```
   #include "ModelDir/ModelName.idl"
   ```
3. In my `build.gradle` I created task that should open, and read those dependencies, preferably return them:

   ```
   class parsingIDL extends DefaultTask{

       String idlFileName="*def file name*"

       def regex = ~/#include .*\/(\w*).idl/

       @Task Action
       def checkDependencies(){
           File idlFile= new File(idlFileName)
           if(!idlFile.exists()){
               logger.error("File not found)
           } else {
               idlFile.eachLine{ line ->
                   def dep = []
                   def matcher = regex.matcher(line)
                   (...)*
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

What should I have in (...)* to find all dependencies and how should I define, that for example

```
subprojectA::build.dependsOn([subprojectB::dist, subprojectC::dist])?
```

All I could find on internet created dep, that outputted given:

```
[]
[]
[modelName]
[]
[]
(...)
```